# insert range data from different cell in a formula excel

Tags: excel

I have the following formula in Excel:

=VLookUp(A3;Data!A3:H80;6;FALSE)

I'd like to take the data range 'Data!A3:H80' from a cell containing this sentence, so that changing the last value (for example from 80 to 150)in the other cell, I can update the formula.
Is there a way to do this?

NB: Data!A3:H8, is from another excel sheet (named Data) of the same file.

Comment: There is no detriment to using full column reference in VLOOKUP `Data!A:H`.  Is there a reason that will not work for you?

Comment: From what I understood, you want to input the numbers for the coordinates in a cell and have that reference directly to your Vlookup. If that's what you are trying to do, you could easily do it in VBA with a concatenate, such as: ="Sheet2!A"&G6&":H"&G7 where G6 and G7 is where you input your coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I assume number '80' is entered into cell K1.

```
=VLookUp(A3;Data!A3:indirect("H"&K1);6;FALSE)
```

change '80' in K1 to '150' to test it.

Hope it works. ( :